# How to use a while loop properly in SAS

Tags: while-loop, sas

I am trying to write a while loop to count how many students fulfill a specific criteria, which is that they are between 10-15 years old, and that they have a score above 50. In my dataset, I have the students' scores and their birth dates (Date-Month-Year).

This is how I have tried to set it up. I have read that the function `INTICK()` should be able to calculate the age as long as I have the date of birth:

```
data qualified;
set students;
DO i=0 UNTIL (10=<INTICK('Year', dob, today())=<15 & Ejection_fraction>50) i++;

proc print data=qualified
```

I don't get the count printed.

Comment: is it because you forgot "; end;" at the end of your code?

Comment: The resultview shows up, but the result for i is not there

Comment: is "i" in "students" table?

Comment: No, it is not there

Comment: where "i" is incremented? like "i=i+1" or other.

Comment: Forgot to write it here, but next to the condition

Comment: You don't need to use a loop here. Just use a `where` statement.

Comment: @J_Lard: So `counter=0; do i=0 where (10=<INTICK('Year', dob, today())=<15 & Ejection_fraction>50); counter=i+1;`

Comment: `INTCK`, for starters, not `INTICK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS automatically loops through records for you, so there's no need for you to code your own loop.  The loop would let you do something else, like iterate over *variables*, but if it's records you're after?  SAS does this for you.

Normally, you would just count them with `proc freq` or similar.

```
proc freq data=students;
  where 10<=INTCK('Year', dob, today())<=15 and Ejection_fraction>50;
run;
```

Or you can make a dataset in a data step.

```
data qualified;
  set students;
  where 10=<INTCK('Year', dob, today())=<15 & Ejection_fraction>50;
run;
```

Looping over records (rows) is rarely useful in SAS.

Comment: I get  `Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string,
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, INPUT, PUT.` Could it be because of the format of the DOB, which i date-month-year?

Comment: No, you have `=<` where you should have `<=` or better `LE`.